# Is RecyclerView better than the viewPager in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager

I've been reading a lot of stuffs for viewPager and found that it is having the feature of loading the previous and next page, but we can still stop this preLoading via **setUserVisibilityHint()** but still the we can't really stop the preLoading as it is just the hack.

About RecyclerView I've heard that we have actually the feature of stopping preLoading. Since I'm very much fond of knowing this stuff as it'll help in my future while dealing with the tabLayout.

Thanks

Comment: A recyclerview is for displaying lists

Comment: "Snapping" might be a problem, but you can try it with the Snaphelper: https://rubensousa.github.io/2016/08/recyclerviewsnap A different issue might be the seizing of a list item that it exactly fills the screen.

Answer (score 2):

Since `Android Support Library 24.2.0`, you can use `RecyclerView` with `SnapHelper` to get paging like in `ViewPager`.

`RecyclerView` is easy to implement and offers much more than ViewPager. For example - You have `ItemAnimator` in `RecyclerView`.

Also, like you said in the question, you can control the preloading in `RecyclerView`.

So, `RecyclerView` should be the ideal choice.

**Note:** Also, performance wise, `RecyclerView` is a better choice. `ViewPager` keeps a left and right page while swiping i.e. Pages of `ViewPager` are created again and again (With 3 pages at any time).

But with `RecyclerView`, you can use `ViewHolder` to use the same page item. So, instead of 3 pages, you will have a just one-page container at any time in which you will be filling details of the current page. This means that you don't have to inflate/create the page container again and again.

Answer (score 2):

This documentation is will get good answer for your requirement.
- The 24.2.0 version of the support library introduced two new classes

> SnapHelper

and

> LinearSnapHelper

[enter image description here](https://rubensousa.github.io/2016/08/recyclerviewsnap) that should be used to handle snapping in a RecyclerView.

[enter link description here](https://rubensousa.github.io/2016/08/recyclerviewsnap)

Answer (score 1):

RecyclerView is better than the viewPager performance wise. Plus you can preload data in recyclerView as compare to viewPager. The Api version 24.2.0 introduce following classes SnapHelper and LinearSnapHelp to give viewPager like look.

see this link how to implement snaphelper [snapHelper Example](https://rubensousa.github.io/2016/08/recyclerviewsnap)